# What is the maximum amount of diamond in one Minecraft game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been wondering - what is the max amount of diamonds I could potentially find in a single Minecraft world?

Comment: Note you can get infinite diamond gear and tools from villager trading, so the 'raw' non-renewable diamonds are only required for enchanting tables, jukeboxes, firework stars with trail effect, and diamond blocks.

Answer (score 60):

There is no fixed amount of Diamond per world, but let's do some math...

This is a calculation for the maximum possible amount. This will likely never happen due to the map size and vein & fortune yield chances, but you asked for the maximum, not for the average.

- a world can be 60 x 60 million blocks, that's 468,750 x 468,750 chunks = **219,726,562,500 chunks**
- [Diamond Ore](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Ore) can appear once per chunk in veins of **1-10 ores**
- in the unlikely event of all veins yielding 10 ores that would be **2,197,265,625,000 ores**
- mining them all with [Fortune](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fortune) 3 could potentially drop **4 diamonds** per ore
- 2,197,265,625,000 ores x 4 = **8,789,062,500,000 diamonds**... happy mining.
- ...and then you can still find more diamonds in treasure chests

Comment: That is several

Comment: And the chance of this happening is so small, that the value is basically meaningless and will never happen, but the OP did ask for **maximum**

Comment: Can you get a fortune 3 pick without having mined a diamond? An enchantment table takes two diamonds per se, plus three for the pick to mine obsidian with. That would bring down the sum to mere 8,789,062,499,985 diamonds.

Comment: @JohnDvorak trading, finding diamonds in loot, finding obsidian in loot...

Comment: You can also trade for the books and use an anvil instead of an enchanting table.  I'm curious how far this differs from the actual maximum from chunk generation, but that'd be quite a bit of computation time to check

Comment: If someone wants to continue this calculation with the maximum of the chest loot, here is a list of the differend kind of chests vs the amount of loot that is inside: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chest_loot (don't forget to count the loot chests in every dimension)

Comment: @Paulpro it certainly is more than one.

Comment: @tox123 I'd say, it's even a tad more than six.

Comment: Can't there also be villagers who will trade you a diamond? That would get you a theoretically unlimited amount of diamonds since you can grow villages, right?

Comment: Yes, as already mentioned in other comments. But it would be too easy to just say 'infinite', that's why I excluded non-mining sources in my calculation. You can't back them up with numbers.

Comment: Villagers don't sell diamonds. They buy them, for 1 emerald, not a great trade. They do sell diamond gear though.

Comment: Also, the fully-generated world would occupy about 64 petabytes of disk storage. So this is all a theoretical exercise.

Answer (score 15):

I know the scicraft server has like 103,000 diamonds, but in total (because the mc world is playable up to 12,000,000 blocks in X/Z, which means 750,000 chunks, with an average of 5 diamond ores per chunk) there are about 3,750,000 diamond ores you could mine.

However, with Fortune III you can on average double the diamonds you get from mining ores, so 7,500,000 diamonds, and with the scicraft RNG (random number generator) manipulator and Fortune III you quadruple your diamonds (because you always get the max of 4 diamonds per ore) so 15,000,000 diamonds.

Note: Beyond the 12,000,000 meters there are still chunks, but your game gets laggy and it's a bad time so I excluded that for the sake of having easy numbers.

**Edit:**

From dly's answer, there are 219,726,562,500 chunks in a 60,000,000 block wide world. On average there is one ore vein with an average of 5 ores per vein, so 1,098,632,812,500 ores in the whole world. However, as stated above, with Fortune III you can on average double your diamonds gained per ore mined, so 2,197,265,625,000 diamonds. With the RNG manipulator also mentioned above you can get the max of 4 for every ore mined, leading to 4,394,531,250,000 diamonds mineable in the whole world.

Additionally, you can find diamonds in loot chests in structures, but calculating the amount is extremely impractical. Diamonds spawn in chests in desert temples, end cities, jungle temples, mineshafts, nether fortresses, shipwrecks, tool smith and weapon smith villagers' houses, and strongholds. All of these but the last are almost unlimited in number and there are no readily accessible figures on how many there are per some amount of chunks.

However, some information can be gotten.

There are 128 strongholds in every world, and .132 diamonds in each portal room chest. So there are ~15 diamonds in all the strongholds.

Additionally, there are jungle temples in 3/4 of jungles and .273 diamonds per chest in each jungle temple, so .546 diamonds per temple, and therefore .4095 diamonds per jungle in jungle temples.

And misc data: every end city chest has ~1 diamond, and there are on average 3 chests per end city, so 3 diamonds per end city. Every 3 nether fortress chests have 1 diamond between them, and every 10 mineshaft and desert temple chests have 1 diamond between them.

If you have data on how often these structures spawn please edit this answer to include it.

Comment: cough item duplication cough

Comment: I have no lag problems beyond 12M blocks. Do you know a bug report for that?

Comment: That was just the "average" X/Z distance where people started getting lag and buggy terrain generation and such, according to a few quick internet searches. Should've made that clear sorry.

Comment: Apparently that figure is wrong too, because dly's answer puts it 18 million blocks farther than mine.

Comment: How old are those reports? It might very well be fixed for years already. And 30M is the world border, it has nothing to do with lag.

Answer (score 10):

If you're up for a non-mathy answer:

Infinite if you have [Mystical Agriculture](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mystical-agriculture) or [Bonsai Trees](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/bonsai-trees) installed. Just grow them.
Alternatively, sieve them from soil in [Ex](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/ex-nihilo)-[Ni](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/ex-nihilo-adscensio)[hilo](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/ex-nihilo-creatio).

In all seriousness though, through normal play, it isn't feasible to get *all* the possible Diamond in the world. You'll only be limited to whatever you find, which at the rate they spawn at - Is unlikely for you to run out of Diamonds... if you keep on exploring outwards (generating new chunks).

So "more than enough", or what might seem like "infinity".

Comment: Agriculture is one option. Another is to get an ex nihilo sifter, pipe an extruder into it, and sift and sift and sift.

Comment: Don't forget trees.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: You should add "Non-Vanilla" to the first paragraph as well.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Another option is any of the variety of tech mods that provide their own infinite ore solution, like Immersive Engineering (semi limited by veins which are seperate from normal ore), Industrial Foregoing (Infinite), IndustrialCraft (allows manufacture from coal and obsidian) or any of a variety of magic mods even up to things like astral sorcery for turning automatically generated stone into ore or botania for the same.

Comment: Do diamonds spawn spontaneously (in non-new chunks) or did you mean the rate they occur in newly spawned chunks which you explore after having triggered their creation? If the latter, that would not be infinite according to dly's answer because worlds have a maximum size.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider This is a matter of perception. Hence the quotes.

Comment: I was just curious what exactly you mean, in particular in the vicinity of "at the rate they spawn". I understand now that you simply mean one is unlikely to run out of the given finite amount in the ground, given the large world size.

Answer (score 4):

In minecraft 1.14.3, there is a bug with drowned where you can duplicate an item that it is holding, which makes diamonds basically infinite. Refer to other answers for older versions.

Comment: Fixed in 1.14.4 pre-release 1